# Is there a way to make the form stop loading data from file after specific data has been found

Tags: c#

I have a windows form application that has bunch of information about 3 different users in a text file. I made a login form that checks the username and password before granting access to the other forms. I would like to know how to make it so that when a specific user has logged on, only his information is loaded into the other forms and not the other users info. So i was wondering if there is a way to make the streamreader stop reading a file after a specific user has been found and only load information about that user?

Any answer or hint will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Can't you just split the file, one for each user? The filename could correspond to the user's ID, or whatever unique means of identifying them.

Comment: Text files aren't as robust as databases.  You can't really be selective with what you fetch from them.

Comment: Dont forget to mark the answer you think it is best when the problem solved. You benefit from the answer, and the users benefit from the reputation they gain. That is how this forum works :D

Answer (score 4):

you can read all the lines of the file, and exit when you find the info you need. Something like this might work for you:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("YOUR PATH GOES IN HERE");

    while(reader.Peek()>=0)
    {
        string yourString = reader.ReadLine();

        if(yourString == "WHATHEVER YOU NEED")
        {
             //YOUR CODE HERE
             break; 
        }
    } 
reader.Dispose();
reader.Close();
```

I hope that helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your code includes a loop within which there is code that parses or processes the data in the text file. Change the loop so that it only continues if data for the currently logged-in user hasn't already been read.